# I want to add comment section and reply section in html page in bootstrap template

Tags: html, comments

I searched a lot about adding a responsive add comment section. But, I am not able to get exact answer. I want to display comments and reply messages in html in bootstrap. I found a PHP code.

Is it possible to get the code or plugin to be incorporated in html to display responsive comments using database ot using xml?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Are you in search of any message form in your site?

Comment: yes jijo. I am searching for message form.when anyone click on post comment. That comment should display with name , message and time